# How to display auto generated emp0001 id in textbox using php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I want to auto increment my employee ID when I add a new employee. At each entry it'll auto increment.

And I have try this code it's shows empty.

And also have a doubt where will I call this function or else give some other idea not asking code

```
public function autoincemp()
{
    global $value2;
    $query = "SELECT empid from tbemployee order by empid desc LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $value2 = $row['empid'];
        $value2 = substr($value2, 3, 5);
        $value2 = (int) $value2 + 1;
        $value2 = "EMP" . sprintf('%04s', $value2);
        $value = $value2;
        return $value;
    } else {
        $value2 = "EMP0001";
        $value = $value2;
        return $value;
    }
```

Comment: Unclear. How did you create your table? Did you set a primary key with autoincreament on in MySql?

Comment: yes i have create a table tbemployee with the column name empid (auto increment,primary key) @Jay Wadhwa

Comment: Since you have set `empid` as primary key and autoincrement. Ignore the field while inserting records from php and it should autoincrement automatically.

Comment: @nixUser Thank you, And  can you pls tell me, how do i call this fuction into the textbox.

Comment: You can remove this function completely and the textbox for empid since it is managed by the database.

Comment: Soryy sir, i m new to this php lang, could pls tell me how to provide it,  if  it's managed by db means the id will generate 1,2,3... but i want to generate EMP0001 like this